# AVPlayer send AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification with about 1 min of playback left

Tags: avplayer

I am trying hls streaming on Mac. For some contents playback doesn't reach till end and AVPlayer sends AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification signal around 1 min of playback left. It always happens around same time.

AVPlayer gets playlist with starting segment =100. It plays fine for about 16 mins in an 18 min video. and then it fails with AVPlayerItemFailedToPlayToEndTimeNotification.

Here is the AVPlayerItem errorlog

```
error log: #Version: 1.0
Software: AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.13E28 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4; en_us)
#Date: 2014/11/14 12:32:17.017
#Fields: date time uri cs-guid s-ip status domain comment
2014/11/14 12:32:15.015 http://localhost:12000/stream/content.ts?id=192.168.1.107-bd1ec9ddb674b1c67dd4&bps=1200000&segid=100 B4A5AB49-1647-4A3B-9768-61F3F99B133E 127.0.0.1 -12318 "CoreMediaErrorDomain" "Segment exceeds specified bandwidth for variant"
```

In the error logs it complains about segment 100 which was played 16 mins ago. It looks like its old error info.

Here is the access log info when the playback fails

```
Access log: #Version: 1.0
#Software: AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.13E28 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4; en_us)
#Date: 2014/11/14 12:32:17.017
#Fields: date time uri cs-guid s-ip s-ip-changes sc-count c-duration-downloaded c-start-time c-duration-watched bytes c-observed-bitrate sc-indicated-bitrate c-stalls c-frames-dropped c-startup-time c-overdue c-reason c-observed-min-bitrate c-observed-max-bitrate c-observed-bitrate-sd s-playback-type sc-wwan-count c-switch-bitrate
2014/11/14 12:32:15.015 https://localhost:12100/stream/playlist.m3u8?id=192.168.1.107-bd1ec9ddb674b1c67dd4&bps=1200000 B4A5AB49-1647-4A3B-9768-61F3F99B133E 127.0.0.1 0 3 9.000 1.070 1.281 1831920 5991597.824 1369642 0 0 2.430 0 - 3063099.199 6966103.615 - VOD 0 -
```

I have compared the access log for AVPlayerItem when the playback fails vs playback is OK (I dump state when playback is paused) and the only notable difference is c-reason field which is 1 in case of failure and - in case of success.

**What is c-reason field and where can I get more information on that**. [AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent) doesn't say anything about it.

Here is the comparision of AVPlayerItemAccessLogEvent fields for fail and success cases. The first value is fail case and second is success case.

```
uri = https://localhost:12100/stream/playlist.m3u8?id=192.168.1.107-bd1ec9ddb674b1c67dd4&bps=1200000
      https://localhost:12100/stream/playlist.m3u8?id=192.168.1.107-bd1ec9ddb674b1c67dd4&bps=1200000
cs-guid = 9B6DFB28-0AB5-4729-9744-5DD1C80AA974
          B4A5AB49-1647-4A3B-9768-61F3F99B133E
s-ip = 127.0.0.1
     = 127.0.0.1         
s-ip-changes = 0
             = 0                 
sc-count = 4
         = 3             
c-duration-downloaded = 12.000
                      = 9.000                                           
c-start-time = 1.070
             = 1.070
c-duration-watched = 3.948
                   = 1.281
bytes = 2368360
      = 1831920
c-observed-bitrate = 4311328.532
                   = 5991597.824                
sc-indicated-bitrate = 1369642
                    =1369642                         
c-stalls =0
         = 0        
c-frames-dropped = 0
                    = 0
c-startup-time = 2.574
                = 2.430
c-overdue = 0
          = 0
c-reason = 1
         = - 
c-observed-min-bitrate = 2987149.809
                     = 3063099.199
c-observed-max-bitrate = 6577841.971
                       = 6966103.615
c-observed-bitrate-sd = - -
s-playback-type = VOD VOD
sc-wwan-count = 0 0 
c-switch-bitrate = - -
```

I know its long question but if someone can check  the difference above let me know why the player fails.

Thanks for reading through this long question.

Regards,
D

Comment: I found that the issue was with the segment that was sent to the player. Check the segment that was sent to the player when it failed (not the segment that is being played). Unfortunately the player doesn't include correct segment number in the error log.